# How to configure Visual Studio 2010 to remember collapsed regions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I collapse some regions in my aspx file in Visual Studio 2010. After closing the project and reopening it (or even closing the file in the editor and reopening it from solution explorer) my collapsed regions are gone and all expanded.

Missed I something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same problem - Visual Studio Express for Web 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Collapsed regions shall be remembered normally, you don't need to configure anything explicitely.

Take a look at this answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f23e2193-fb17-4ee7-bb51-61b0564317b1/visual-studio-2010-code-collapseexpand?forum=vseditor

It seems to be a problem of your settings, try to reset it like this:

> ...
>
> I tried as you mentioned but cannot reproduce this issue, my
>   VS2010 can remember the collapse situation on my side.
>
> And as far as I know, all the collapse information is stored at .suo
>   file.
>
> I suggest to reset your visual studio by execute command
>
> devenv /resetuserdata
>
> devenv /resetallsettings
>
> in VS2010 command prompt.